# Java - XML digital signature with more references

Tags: java, xml, reference, digital-signature

I am trying to create XML digital signature using Java.
My code looks like:

```
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
// create Reference to Object element
Reference objectRef = fac.newReference(
    "#Res",
    fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null)
);
// create Reference to KeyInfo element
Reference keyInfoRef = fac.newReference(
    "#KeyInfo",
    fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null)
);
```

My problem is, that I need to create XML digital signature with two references - reference to Res object and to KeyInfo. After creating two reference elements and called method for sign, Java gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID KeyInfo
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:431)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.digest(DOMReference.java:359)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.digestReference(DOMXMLSignature.java:496)
at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:379)
at XmlDigitalSignatureGenerator.generateXmlDigitalSignature(XmlDigitalSignatureGenerator.java:108)
at Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is very simple!

Comment: `KeyInfo` is only created during signature generation. It may be that the API doesn't allow signing the `KeyInfo` directly. If this `KeyInfo` is used to select the key for verification then signing it won't provide much additional security. In general the verification keys are already signed, being part of a *certificate*, so there isn't that much use for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Using a validating schema which will register the elements with ID references i could solve this issue

```
XMLStructure content = new DOMStructure(doc.getDocumentElement());
XMLObject obj = fac.newXMLObject(Collections.singletonList(content), "KeyInfo", null, null);
```

Now the "keyInfo" is registered and hence will allow the signature.